# WPF DataGridCell IsReadOnly via XAML depending on a property

Tags: wpf, datagrid, readonly-attribute

I need to set IsReadOnly property on a datagridCell depending on a property.

```
        <WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGrid Grid.Row="2" 
                              InternalAddCommandHandling="False"
                              InternalDeleteCommandsHandling="False" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Command="{Binding Path=AttributesCommand}">
        <WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGrid.Columns>
            <WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGridTextColumn Header="Attribute" Tag="ID_ATTRIBUTE" Width="*" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=FL_COMMON, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Tag="ID_VALUE" Width="*" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        </WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGrid.Columns>
    </WPFCtrlDG:ExtDataGrid>

public BindingList<SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE> Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            if (Context.SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE == null)
                Controller.Execute(delegate(IResult result)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    parameters.Add("FL_ACTIVE", true);
                    parameters.Add("CD_SPL2", CurrentSPL2.CD_SPL2);

                    Model.Invalidate(typeof(SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE), Filter.GENERIC<SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE>(parameters, "ID_ATTRIBUTE"));
                    if (Model.Appendload(result) == false)
                        return false;

                    return result.Successful;
                });
            return Context.SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE;
        }
        set { Context.SPC_SPL2_ATTRIBUTE = value; }
    }
```

FL_COMMON is a boolean property, and is inside the objects displayed in the datagrid, but the code I wrote is not working, while if I set IsreadOnly to true it works.

What am I doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: Can you share the structure of class which you are binding to the ItemSource?

Comment: Added, it is a bindingList loaded from a Database

Comment: Where is `FL_COMMON` compared to the `Attributes` property? It should be a property on the items inside the `Attributes` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call OnPropertyChanged("FL_COMMON"); in the setter?

The class that contains FL_COMMON should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the property should look like something like this:

```
    private bool _FL_COMMON;
    public bool FL_COMMON
    {
        get { return _FL_COMMON; }
        set
        {
            _FL_COMMON = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FL_COMMON");
        }
    }
```